# Lookup value not being copied

Tags: lookup-column

I am using following xml code (copy.asmx > method CopyIntoItems). Per Microsoft [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvccopy.copy.copyintoitems(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvccopy.copy.copyintoitems%28v=office.14%29.aspx) I should be able to update lookup fields value as well because Lookup list is on the same subsite and both source and target libraries are on the same sub-site as well. Any idea? Item gets copies and all the columns get populated except the lookup column. I verified that the ID and value matches for the lookup value. (by the way http is there I had to take it out b/c of the forum rule)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <soap:Header>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:CopyIntoItems>
      <m:SourceUrl>internal.col.com/sales/bymonth/Active/0973410.pdf</m:SourceUrl>
      <m:DestinationUrls>
        <m:string>internal.col.com/sales/bymonth/NonActive/0973410.pdf</m:string>
      </m:DestinationUrls>
      <m:Fields>
        <m:FieldInformation Type="Text" DisplayName="Sales Code" InternalName="SalesID" Value="99999"></m:FieldInformation>
        <m:FieldInformation Type="Text" DisplayName="Sales Person Name" InternalName="FullName" Value="TEST, John S."></m:FieldInformation>
        <m:FieldInformation Type="Choice" DisplayName="FileSection" InternalName="PersonnelFileSection" Value="1- New Hire Paperwork, ECA, Termination, LOA"></m:FieldInformation>
        <m:FieldInformation Type="Choice" DisplayName="FileCategory" InternalName="PersonnelFileCategory" Value="Termination Paperwork"></m:FieldInformation>
        <m:FieldInformation Type="Text" DisplayName="Year" InternalName="Record_x0020_Year" Value="2014"></m:FieldInformation>
        <m:FieldInformation Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Effective Date" InternalName="Anniversary" Value="04/22/2014 00:00:00"> </m:FieldInformation>
        <m:FieldInformation Type="Choice" DisplayName="Status" InternalName="Current_x0020_Status" Value="Terminated"></m:FieldInformation>
        <m:FieldInformation Type="Lookup" DisplayName="AreaCode" InternalName="AreaCode" Id="cdae6ca0-d49c-4971-a580-2adcd7a282f1"  Value="4;#1795004"></m:FieldInformation>        
        <m:FieldInformation Type="Text" DisplayName="Title" InternalName="Title" Value="TEST"></m:FieldInformation>
      </m:Fields>
      <m:Stream>base64Binary</m:Stream>
    </m:CopyIntoItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please share the link to the article you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry. Just updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sweet Powershell script I use for fixing Lookup fields (they break often in my experience) Just plug in your parameters in the function call on bottom :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
Function Fix-LookupColumn ($webURL, $listName, $columnName, $lookupListName)
{
  #Get web, list and column objects
  $web = Get-SPWeb $webURL
  $list = $web.Lists[$listName]
  $column = $list.Fields[$columnName]
  $lookupList = $Web.Lists[$lookupListName]

  #Change schema XML on the lookup column
  $column.SchemaXml = $column.SchemaXml.Replace($column.LookupWebId.ToString(), $web.ID.ToString())
  $column.SchemaXml = $column.SchemaXml.Replace($column.LookupList.ToString(), $lookupList.ID.ToString())
  $column.Update()

#Write confirmation to console and dispose of web object
write-host "Column" $column.Title "in list" $list.Title "updated to lookup list" $lookupList.Title "in site" $web.Url
$web.Dispose()
}

Fix-LookupColumn -webURL http://server/site -listName "ListName" -columnName   "ColumnName" -lookupListName "LookupList"
```

Comment: Colbs, Thanks for the powershell script. Do you know a way to incorporate powershell script from workflow. The code I posted is in the workflow action item (calling a web service)

Comment: I have never done that. This would be more for a one off fix post render. I don't believe Lookup fields are supported through the copy webservice. If it is part of a workflow, maybe you can do it through the Object Model